# ResquestMapping JSONARRAY empty and false in return

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, rest

Good Morning,
I created a webservice Rest using spring 4, but the response on the screen appears false and empty. Could someone tell me why?

Follow the code:

@RestController
    public class Controller {

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info/{param1}/{param2}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<JSONObject> search (@PathVariable(value = "param1") String param1,
            @PathVariable(value = "param2") Long param, final HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException, SQLException, DaoException, ForbiddenException {

        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();;
        List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

            for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){ 

                json1.put("JSON1", myrequest1);
                json2.put("JSON2", myrequest2);

                jsonList.add(json1);
                jsonList.add(json2);

            }

        return jsonList; >>>>>>Here json appears filled in correctly
    }
```

In postman:

```
[
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "false and empty"? Please provide some more informations.

Comment: hi tks for your comment... I means in this image:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/1-png-ebcf92a0-4004-401c-a410-938e8426f82a

in return jsonList; >>>>>>Here json appears filled in correctly
is ok...ideia?